# Why are the font sizes different

Tags: html, css, font-size

I've got the following html and css
In Firefox the computed font size is 16.66667px
In Chrome the computed font size is 13px

Needless to say there is a good bit of difference in these two sizes, one is too small to read, one is nicely sized.  I guess one way to work around it is to set the font size to 16.67px but why is this the case.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <title>My first styled page</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 10pt;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

    This is some text.
</body>
</html>
```

All my measurements come from inspect element (using firebug in firefox).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font sizes are different because the browser programmers make different assumptions about the normal user's system.

There's nothing wrong with that, and this is also why you should **not** use `px` to set the font size. On a computer with a high-resolution screen, your font will be too small. Certainly 10px will be unreadable on many people's computers.

I recommend [How to Size Text in CSS](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/howtosizetextincss/) for a good overview of your choices.

Comment: Now that's what I'm talkin' about.

Comment: Article completely antiquated.

Comment: @resio: happy to see your link to a better one. @kingjeffrey: the other answer suggested `px`.

Comment: @egrunin: the whole issue is irrelevant since browsers went to "zoom"ing instead of text resizing

Comment: @resio: only irrelevant if you don't mind a high bounce rate.

Answer (score 1):

`pt` is a unit used for print and is not reliable for cross browser screen sizing.  Try using another unit like `px`, `em` or a straight percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the font size in `PX` like `font-size:10px`

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: +1 It may not address the OP's question in a strict sense, but it resolves the OP's problem: inconsistent font sizes across multiple browsers.