# Why computed font-size in browser devtools is different from my stylesheet value?

Tags: css, browser, font-size

- in my external stylesheet 'font-size' property is defined for 'body' element only, and is '10px'
- however, in Opera, Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox devtools 'computed' value for 'font-size' is 13.33px for 'body', 'div', 'p' and 26.66px for 'h1'
- of course network caching is disabled
- it is strange, since today's default 'font-size' for 'user agent stylesheet' is 16px
- so, where is this coefficient 1.33 from ? - why then not 1.6 ?
- neither Google nor the following article didn't help
  [Why are the font sizes different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269986/why-are-the-font-sizes-different)
- how can I get rid of this font boost ? - some hack would be appreciated
- it's rather annoying...

Comment: share your full CSS and you will get the logical explanation of the result

Comment: it's here https://yadi.sk/d/cINf2OXr3Y2HJk

Answer (score 0):

You have set the body font size to `10pt` not `10px`

1pt = 1.33333px

Comment: Unbelievable ! - Thank you. It works correctly with 10px